# Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using ajax to filter a profession in a professional listing. But it asks me this error: Can not set property 'innerHTML' of null.
The ajax code is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var req;
function filtro_pesquisa(valor) {   

if(window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ 
req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
} 
else if(window.ActiveXObject) 
{ 
req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
}  
var url = "pesquisa.php?valor="+valor;   
req.open("Get", url, true);   
req.onreadystatechange = function() {   
if(req.readyState == 1) 
{ document.getElementById('col-md-4').innerHTML = 'A procurar...'; 
}   
if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) 
{
document.getElementById('col-md-4').innerHTML = '';
var resposta = req.responseText;   
document.getElementById('col-md-4').innerHTML = resposta; 

} 
} 
req.send(null); 
}
</script>
```

the form of research is:

```
 <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                     <h5 style="color:black;"> Encontre um profissional</h5>
                        <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Profissão" name="profissao" id="profissao" oninput="filtro_pesquisa(this.value);" autocomplete="off">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Pesquisar</button>
                        </span>         
        </div>
        </form>
```

I still have the pesquisa.php file and the listing code that is in "col-md-4" div class.
When I try to do a search is one mistake that me appears. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you don't have element with id 'col-md-4'. Hence this error is throwing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-md-4` should be a class, not id.  It's also no where to be found in your markup.

Comment: col-md-4 it is a class im1dermike

Comment: @Claudia: then don't try to access it via `getElementById()`...